# How to generate XML file without using ActiveX plugin using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox

I am facing problem in generating **XML** file in  firefox/chrome using javascript.

I can generate XML file in internet explorer browser , but it uses ActiveX plugin .I want to generate the same on other mentioned browser without using ActiveX.

Anyone can suggest me some good approach ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Comment: @AlexSlipknot  I need to create XML file , not only text file and need to modify also

Comment: You can modify provided example for your purpose

Comment: @AlexSlipknot I don't want to create memory .. i need to use on local drive .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with blob data. So you can download file generated in browser:

```js
function saveXMLFile(filename, data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/xml'});
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else{
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        elem.download = filename;        
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();        
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
}

saveXMLFile('my.xml', '<root><elem>hello</elem></root>');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gph57dtb/)

Comment: Thanks for your help . But this wasn't the exact answer. I solved it anyway.